# PHP PDO Statement: Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

What is wrong in this code?

```
$statement = $dbConn->prepare("CALL SearchUser(?)");
$statement->bindParam(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 4000);
```

This is the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SearchUser(IN Username VARCHAR(10), OUT numRows INT) 
BEGIN SELECT COUNT(*) INTO numRows 
FROM USER
WHERE Username='IN'; 
END//
```

The error is: Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE, expected 2 got 1.
Why? Thank you.

Comment: Where do you supply an argument for `numRows`?

Comment: I don't know what you mean; numRows must be the output parameter of the procedure. Isn't that so? Thanks.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382922/calling-stored-procedure-with-out-parameter-using-pdo or maybe  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118506/stored-procedures-mysql-and-php/4502524#4502524 ether way read both answers

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass two parameter

```
$statement = $dbConn->prepare("CALL SearchUser(?,?)");
$statement->bindParam(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 4000);
$statement->bindParam(2, $rowcount, PDO::PARAM_INT|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT);
```

You could refer this [article](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.php.doc/doc/t0023502.html)

Comment: But rowcount is the output parameter of the procedure, why do I have to pass it? Anyway I tried with this result:
1414 OUT or INOUT argument 2 for routine SearchUser is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger

Comment: when you are getting output, you need to hold it somewhere. right ?

Comment: @JamieITGirl What you are referring, is seems to be a bug. Please refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428480/php-bindparam-does-not-seem-to-work-with-a-param-int-out-parameter

Comment: @JamieITGirl I was not sure about your complete code otherwise I would have updated the answer

Comment: But I have mysql  version 5.6.35! I quote:
"It’s been fixed for version 5.5.3+ & 6.0.8+."

Comment: @JamieITGirl try the approach mentioned in that answer ?

Comment: The example it's about a procedure which takes a string and returns a string. My procedure takes a string and returns an int. I tried this but doesn't work (fatal error: Using $this when not in object context).  
statement = $dbConn->prepare("CALL SearchUser(:username, @numrows)");  
$statement->bindParam(':username', $numRows);  $statement->execute();  
$numRows = $this->dbConn->query("select @numrows")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);